# Passing a var from server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using node.js + Express + EJS.

In my route, I'm accessing an external API to get some data:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var request = https.get(url + 'products.json', function(response){
    var buffer = "", 
    route;

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
    }); 

    response.on("end", function (err) {
    // finished transferring data
    // dump the raw data
    console.log(buffer);
    console.log("\n");
    data = JSON.parse(buffer);
    route = data;

    }); 
});

res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Home',
    products: JSON.stringify(data)

});
});
exports.router = router;
exports.products = data;
```

My goal is to pass this data variable to the client side. 
In my app.js file I set -

```
app.locals.productsData = routes.products;
```

In my index.ejs file this is what I'm trying to do -

```
 <script>
var products = <%= products %>;
</script>
```

or stuff like

```
    <script>
        var products = <%= {{productsData}} %>;
    </script>
```

I can't seem to find a way to pass this data.

Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `res.render` in the wrong place (data will only have its value later, when `request` will send its `end` event.

So you need to move the `res.render` inside the `end` event callback.

Try

```
response.on("end", function (err) {
    // finished transferring data
    // dump the raw data
    var data = JSON.parse(buffer);
    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Home',
      products: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
});
```

with

```
<script>
var products = "<%= products %>";
</script>
```

Comment: I get an exception on the client side - 
    var products = [object Object]

Comment: I proposed a fix ; hard to debug across stack overflow ;-) + try with `products: 7' instead of `products: JSON.stringify(data)` to check that ejs is working

Comment: Now I get - 
products = "[object Object]"